# TYPO3 - TMENU error

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am building menu in TYPO3 template - setup.

This is typoscript code from template - setup:

```
menuSecondary = HMENU
menuSecondary {
    special = directory
    special.value = 11

    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      NO = 1
      NO {
        linkWrap = <li>|</li>
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is, this **1 = TMENU**, since I have defined `1 = TMENU` I got this error in browser:

***"[] operator not supported for strings"***

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a hidden (invisible) char in your TS? Check with an IDE or an hex editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with TYPO3 7.6.15 and PHP 7.1 ([Bug report](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79001)). It was already fixed and will be included in the next release 7.6.16 that is scheduled for Tuesday, February 28th, 2017 ([source](https://typo3.org/news/article/regular-maintenance-release-schedule/)).

Until the release you can apply the patch manually. You find the patch [here](https://review.typo3.org/#/c/50974/).

Also keep in mind that TYPO3 7LTS does **not** officially support PHP 7.1 but TYPO3 8LTS will ([source](https://typo3.org/download/)).